# C# row filter shows `System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Mod' operator.'`

Tags: c#, datatable

**This is the code:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (documentName.Text.Length > 0)
{
    sb.Append("document_name like '%" + documentName.Text + "%'");
}

if (section.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(" and ");
    }

    sb.Append("section_number like %" + Int32.Parse(section.Text) + "%");
}


(data.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
```

**Goal:**

I am aiming to create a Multi Text box search bar to filter the dataGridview

**Detail:**

Using Document name text box on it's own works fine.. but when both are combined or the section is used.. it throws me this error:

`System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Mod' operator.'`

Comment: Can you show us the line which is giving the error?

Comment: @viveknuna `(data.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();`

Comment: what is datatype of `data`?

Comment: You are missing singlequotes in `section_number like %"`... You should be doing `sb.Append("section_number like '%" + Int32.Parse(section.Text) + "%'");`

Comment: It is loaded using MySQLconnection and MySQLDataadapter.. let me edit the question

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : `'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.'`

Comment: if `section.Text` is a numeric value the you should not use like operator. You should user `=` operator. `sb.Append("section_number = " + section.Text);`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I had to remove `like` and place the `=`. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

The quotation marks in the expression

"section_number like %" + Int32.Parse(section.Text) + "%"

are missing (before and after the %).

Comment: `: 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.'`